# how to find the descendants of the first level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Please help to fix the script.

```
import pprint
import requests

import bs4


def get_catalog(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    if req.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        print('Error: ', req.status_code)
    else:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text)
        #print(soup)
        catalogMenu = soup.find('section', {'class': 'catalog'})
        catalogMenuList = catalogMenu.find('ul', {'class': 'topnav'})
        #print(catalogMenuList)

        return catalogMenuList


def parse_catalog_categories(catalogMenuList):
    catalogNames = []
    #li = catalogMenuList.findNext('li', limit=1)   #?????????????????
    pprint.pprint(li)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'http://first-store.ru/'
    catalogMenuList = get_catalog(url)
    if not catalogMenuList:
        print('Get catalog error')
    else:
        parse_catalog_categories(catalogMenuList)
```

The problem is that I can't find all the descendants of `li` first level of nesting. ie:

```
iphone, ipad, ipod, imac, etc...
```

But not:

```
iphone, iphone 5s, iphone 5s VIP, iphone 5c, .....
```

Comment: please, include relevant input/output in your question. In particular, could you show a *small* html fragment with `<li>` items and the corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 7):

Try to set `recursive=False` to search only among direct children of the tag:

```
items = catalogMenuList.find_all('li', recursive=False)
```